# How can I interpret variables in a bunch in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, interpretation, shapley-value

I have 15 variables and 1 output and I have fitted a Random Forest Model. And then connected it to a SHAP intepretation framework.

But, I want to find out the combined effect of three bunches of variables

B1 - x1, x2

B2 - x3, x4, x5, x6

B3 - x7,..., x15

Variables in B1, B2, B3 have some physical connections with each other. So, I want to get to a point where I can comment that B1 can explain 30% of the model, B2 can explain 20% of the model etc.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Comment: This feels a lot like what analysis of variance does, except your model is non-linear. I may be pointing you in the wrong direction, but that's something I would look into if I were you

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to calculate this percentage variance for SHAP?

Answer (score 0):

Shapley values are pretty flexible given the way they are computed. The most straightforward way is to use the 'brute force'/traditional Shapley value regression approach. That is, I am not aware of SHAP-like variants (i.e., that make approximations to Shapley values) that allow for grouping features in the literature outside of summing the individual values by group (which will not produce the same result as grouping them in estimation unless the features are completely uncorrelated).

In traditional Shapley value regression, you can group the features together where they are included or excluded from the coalition together. An example, implemented in R, is shown below using the `modeldata::ames` data.

```
domir::domir(
    Sale_Price ~ Half_Bath + Full_Bath + First_Flr_SF + Second_Flr_SF + Garage_Type + Garage_Finish, 
    \(fml) {
        set.seed(8232023)
        randomForest::randomForest(fml, data = modeldata::ames) |> 
          predict() |> 
          yardstick::rsq_trad_vec(modeldata::ames$Sale_Price, estimate = _)
     }, 
     .set = list(Bath = ~ Half_Bath + Full_Bath, SQFT = ~ First_Flr_SF + Second_Flr_SF, Garage = ~ Garage_Type + Garage_Finish),
     .cdl = FALSE, .cpt = FALSE)
)
```

Here variables related to number of bathrooms, house square footage, and details about the garage are grouped such that they are included or excluded jointly in the computations much like the situation you describe seeking to evaluate.

The result of this function is:

```
Overall Value:      0.7671851 

General Dominance Values:
       General Dominance Standardized Ranks
Bath           0.1626241    0.2119750     3
SQFT           0.4169509    0.5434815     1
Garage         0.1876101    0.2445435     2
```

The `{domir}` package is a 'Dominance Analysis' function but the 'General Dominance Values' it produces are Shapley values and can be used as such.

As can be seen, the groups of factors produce an exact decomposition of the $R^2$ for the overall model as was sought in the original post.